# Popup boxes won't close properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

So I've made a page with a popup box code and I used it for 3 pop ups, the problem is, they won't close properly when I click on another link. Like if I open one popup and then on another, the last one is not closing and they keep stacking up even though I've specified close, won't work with hide, tried that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {//$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function(){
var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size
var query= popURL.split('?');
var dim= query[1].split('&');
var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value
$('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"></a>');
var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 10) / 2;
var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;
//Apply Margin to Popup
$('#' + popID).css({
'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
});
$('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
$('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'})
return false;
});
$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() {
$('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
$('#fade, a.close').remove(); //fade them both out
});
return false;
});
});
```

CSS:

```
.popup_block{
    display:none;
    background:#151515;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    top:40%;left:50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    line-height:20px;

}

*html #fade {position: absolute;}
*html .popup_block {position: absolute;}
#fade {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:30%;
    top:0px;
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:9999;
    background:#000; /* change to #fff for solid white */
    opacity:1; /* change to opacity:1; */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box1" class="popup_block">
HEY
</div>
 <div id="box2" class="popup_block">
    YO
 </DIV>
  <div id="box3" class="popup_block">
 hello
 </div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things wrong with the code you posted. I'm not sure if it's a result of copying just a piece from the whole thing, but the `</div></div></div></div>` thing caught my eye right away. I popped what you had into a JsFiddle and cleaned things up. You're using a lot of IDs with `#`, which personally I'd avoid doing unless absolutely necessary. Your close function may not have been working because of the ID conflict between multiple `#fade` elements. You'll see I replaced IDs with classes and it works.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var popID = $(this).attr("class"); 
        var tarDiv = $("div." + popID);
        var popMargTop = (tarDiv.height() + 10) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = (tarDiv.width() + 80) / 2; 
        tarDiv.fadeIn()
            .css({
                "width": 300,
                "margin-top": -popMargTop,
                "margin-left": -popMargLeft
            });
        var closeA = $("<a href=\"#\" class=\"close\">X</a>");
        closeA.appendTo(tarDiv)
            .click(closeMe);
        var fadeDiv = $("<div class=\"fade\" style=\"filter:alpha(opacity=80);\" />");
        fadeDiv.appendTo($("body"))
            .fadeIn()
            .click(closeMe);
        function closeMe() {
            $(".fade , .popup_block").fadeOut(function() {
                $(".fade, a.close").remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/kprwnzcc/

Comment: Hey! Thank you for answering this but it still won't work, you see in the fiddle as well, when you click on  box 1 and then box2, it just overlaps the previous box. Try clicking box1, box2, box3 then box2 and box1, it just messes up. The previous boxes won't close, that's the main issue. Please if you could help me with that I'll be able to put up my portfolio. Thank you again jessikwa!

Comment: In that case on your click event you would want to call the `closeMe()` function to close any existing dialogs, _then_ create the new dialog.